When will Azure Task Xcode@5 support xcodeVersion 15?
When we archive our package using Xcode@5 with default or 14 as xcodeVersion set and push to Testflight using AppStoreRelease@1, apple supply a warning in the confirmation email as follows:

ITMS-90725: SDK version issue - This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution.

Code:
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive'
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(XC_WORK_SPACE_PATH)'
    configuration: 'release'
    exportPath: '$(ARCHIVE_PATH)'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    scheme: '$(TF_VAR_SCHEME)'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' // or '14' has the same issue  
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(TF_VAR_APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(TF_VAR_APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'

When we update Xcode@5 to use 15 as xcodeVersion, it gives the error:

##[error]Error: Unable to resolve the developer path for Xcode 15. Set the XCODE_15_DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable on the agent machine, or set Xcode version to Default or Specify path.

We're not using a self hosted agent and we're running it from the cloud with macos-latest. We didn't have to do this for any previous version.  Is this how we should proceed in order to make use of xcode 15 or will there be an update to Xcode@5 to cater for xcodeversion 15?

Please change to agent macOS-13, the default xcode is 15, and it has iOS17.
MacOS-latest points to macOS-12, default xcode version is 14, it doesn't have Xcode 15 and iOS17.

You can click the links inside the doc for the agents software details.

Thanks for sharing this! I was just about to post my own answer but then I saw yours. It turns out that my mistake was assuming that 'macos-latest' meant the latest macOS version, which isn't the case.

Yes,  actually the latest Mac hosted agent is macOS-13, macOS-latest points to macOS-12. Not sure why the comment is removed, add it again. Glad to know it's clear for you now. Happy coding!

Thanks for the answer. It helps me to solve issues quickly and the attached link is life saver :).
